# Can an Android in-app browser be exited?

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm building an Android app using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), which means all of my code is in html and javascript but is compiled to a native app.

Phonegap has an "in-app browser" that allows users to be smoothly directed to webpages without leaving the app. I've gotten the browser to open; my problem is that I can't get it to close after that. There seems to be no exit button or any way of quitting the browser from the inside.

Is there a way to configure the in-app browser so that it has an exit button? Or -- even better -- is there a way to wrap a custom header or frame around the browser? Like the Facebook app for ios, which wraps its own navigation frame around external webpages that users can view inside the app

Comment: what happens if you press back button while in the browser? oh, I don't know anything about phonegap, but android applications has got WebViews, thery're browsers you can embed in your app, very convenient indeed. maybe you can use WebView with phonegap as well

Comment: I actually can't even see the back button right now -- the navigation bar hasn't shown up no matter what I've tried. I'll keep fiddling and see if I can get this to happen

Comment: afaik, if the device hasn't hardware navigation keys, the navigation bar can be darken (and keys become little dots) but not hidden, otherwise how could you exit the app?

Comment: You could try calling the `.close()` function of `InAppBrowser`. New code in `InAppBrowser` lets you insert custom JavaScript to execute, maybe you can store a reference to the outside JS calling the IAB and close it from that code when the user hits your button. Haven't tried but it seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the inAppBrowser with `_blank` set then the browser should open with a navigation bar with a 'Done' button that allows you to dismiss the browser:

`window.open("http://www.ibm.com", "_blank", "location=yes");`